# Как получить значения переменных, которых нет в результате выполнения выборки?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Работаю в Oracle 8. Подскажите как реализовать следующую задачу.

Есть набор переменных: `(a=1;b=2;c=null;d=null)`.
Есть выборка:

```
Select k1 from t1 where id =222 union
Select k2 from t1 where id =222
```

Результат выборки: `(3,4,5,6,7)`

Мне нужно получить те значения переменных, которых нет в результате выполнения запроса, т. е. `(1,2)`. Как такое можно проделать?

Comment: Конвертируйте набор значений переменных в таблицу (`WITH cte AS (SELECT 'a' AS var_name, @a AS var_value FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'b' ...)`) - и решение станет совершенно очевидным.

Comment: как дополнительный вариант, можно посмотреть в сторону `minus` еще. Если оно было в 8 Oracle. Где вы откопали эту древность?)

Comment: @Akina  В 8-й версии не было CTE, как вчера помню.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос, что вы уже пытались сделать и что не получилось.

Comment: @0xdb Ну тады в подзапросе.

Answer (score 2):

Поместите набор переменных в коллекцию, а в запросе воспользуйтесь [*collection unnesting*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/state21b.htm#2066025).
Попробуйете:

```sql
create or replace type numberList is table of number
/
create table t1 as select column_value k1 from table (numberList (3,4,5,6,7));  

set serveroutput on
declare
    nlist numberList := numberList (1, 2, null, null);
    found numberList; 
begin
    select column_value k bulk collect into found 
    from table (nlist) t
    minus
    select k1 -- здесь полный запрос как в вопросе
    from t1 
    ;
    for i in 1..found.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line (found (i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Результат:

> 1
>   2